# Batch file run via command prompt vs Processbuilder

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, processbuilder

I have an issue in running a batch file ("Input.bat") using Java Processbuilder but it works as expected when I run this via command prompt (as batch):

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Batch Started
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Error
SET u=%1
ECHO %u%
ECHO %u%> Input.txt
GOTO End
:Error
ECHO No Input Found
:End
```

The problem is it is not writing the input parameter value to the file "Input.txt" when I run via Processbuilder. The batch is surely executed but not writing any from "ECHO %u%> Input.txt"

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "C:\Input.bat", "Hello as input");
Process p1 = pb.start();
```

Any clue?

Comment: First, how do you know "[t]he batch is surely executed"?  Second, what's the working directory of your Java process?  The use of the file name `Input.txt`  means the file will be created in the working directory of the process.

Comment: My bad, yes its going to my working directory!!

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of trying to redirect the output to a file, you will have more success if you read from the Process's InputStream.

For example:

```
//Start the builder and retrieve the created process
Proccess process = pb.start();
BufferedReader br;
String line;  

//Get the regular output from the process
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
  process.getInputStream()));

while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
  System.out.println(line);
}
br.close();
```

You can also get any error output:

```
//Get error output
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
  process.getErrorStream()));

 while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
 {
   System.out.println(line);
 }
 br.close();
```

These two InputStreams will capture anything sent to standard output or standard error. Once you capture it you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: " redirect the output to a file " - that's not my requirement I am afraid. I need to write the data to that file and it's part of my logic.. The code I shared is just a sample.

Comment: You can use Java itself to write to the file. Capture the standard output of the process and then write that to a File. It may be easier than trying to figure out how to make that work from a batch file that is run via Java.